# UITableViewCell reloadcellsAtIndexPaths increases the height of the following cell but not the actual one

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

after this I am increasing the height of the 1st cell in heightforRowAtIndexPath. But to my surprise it is increasing the height of the second cell, but when I scroll the table view... the height of the first one is set back to desired.

If I reload the entire table using [tv reloaddata] it works fine.. does not work only if i do the particular cell

Any help on this would be helpful..

Comment: You will probably need to show a little more code to get help with this one. Is it the same if you just do [table reloadData] and refresh the whole thing?

Comment: i have made the changes to the description.. thanks Adam.

Comment: yeah — `[tv reloaddata]` definitely is a bit more code.

Comment: @vikingosegundo ahhh.. do u think that's funny??? go S**t on ur blog for fun not here..

Comment: calm down, calm down. I am just preparing an answer for u. but that it quit difficult, as u really didn't give enough information about what u want. so i am guessing. But actually — yes. To provide 2 more words of code when being asked for more code is quite funny.

Comment: btw: I am a non-native English-speaker — what does S**t stand for?

Comment: Still wondering what S**t stands for.

Comment: Still wondering what S**t stands for.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments above, I only have a vague understanding about what you want to achieve. I *assume* you want to extend cell by changing their height. You just mention the first cell, but I guess, you want to be able, to do it for any cell when being clicked.

The complete project is available at [github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/ExtendingCells)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
    NSDictionary *articles;
}

@end
```

.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectedIndexPath = nil;
    articles = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three",
                                                    @"four", @"five", @"six",
                                                    @"seven", @"eight", @"nine",
                                                    @"ten", @"eleven", nil]
                 forKey:@"title"] retain];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [selectedIndexPath release];
    [articles release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[articles allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[articles allKeys] objectAtIndex : section];
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id key = [[articles allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[articles objectForKey : key] count];
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ((selectedIndexPath != nil) && (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row))
        return 80.0;
    return 40.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    id key = [[articles allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[articles objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (selectedIndexPath == indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath : indexPath animated : NO];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

This code is quite rough, as I just extracted it from a project in my very early iPhone-days. i.e. properties are missing.